# Stop Microsoft's Remote Desktop disconnecting me when another user logs on

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, remote-desktop

I work on a macbook in my office at home, but used to work on a Windows machine which is still in my house. To be able to use Windows-specific apps and to get at old files I have set up a way for me to connect to the Windows machine via a Remote Desktop interface.

I use this rarely, but when I do it is frustrating that anyone else in the household logging onto the Windows machine physically causes me to be kicked from my Remote Desktop session.

Is there a way to disable physical log-on while I am connected via Remote Desktop?

Comment: Of course it would be ideal to only disallow physical log-ons when it is my Macbook which is connected to prevent possible attackers gaining access, but this is not a requirement; I do not see myself as being the target of many attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it would be possible without using a third-party software.  I found a couple of articles dealing with [How to Enable Concurrent Remote Desktop Sessions in Windows](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows.html) and [Remote Desktop Connection Without Locking Remote Computer Session on Disconnect](https://techjourney.net/remote-desktop-connection-without-locking-remote-computer-session-on-disconnect/).

In my opinion, you might be better off installing [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/) and using that instead of RDC.

Comment: Does TeamViewer allow a Mac to control and access a Windows computer?

Comment: Yes it does, but I'm not sure this is the best suggestion as TeamViewer has had some security issues lately (even with 2FA turned on): http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/06/teamviewer-users-are-being-hacked-in-bulk-and-we-still-dont-know-how/